# awk to insert value and remove field

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to insert a value into `$4` based of a pattern in `$5`, then remove `$5`. `$4` already has a value in it I am trying to insert the new value in front of it with a `:` between the two values. The `awk` does execute but not as expected. Thank you :).

**f**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    629031  GT:CN   4   High Copy Gain
chr1    632301  GT:CN   3   CN Gain
chr1    6440431 GT:CN   2   CN Loss
chr1    16691021    GT:CN   1   Homozygous Copy Loss
chr1    6440431 GT:CN   0   CN Loss
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '{if ( $5~ /CN/ ) {print $4 ":" "0/1"} else {print $ ":" "1/1"}}' OFS="\t" f.txt | awk -F'\t' '!($5="")'
```

**current**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1 629031 GT:CN 4
3:0/1
2:0/1
chr1 16691021 GT:CN 1
0:0/1
```

**desired**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    629031  GT:CN   1/1:4
chr1    632301  GT:CN   0/1:3
chr1    6440431 GT:CN   0/1:2
chr1    16691021    GT:CN   1/1:1
chr1    6440431 GT:CN    0/1:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
$ awk -F'\t' '{$4=(($5~/CN/)?0:1)"/1:"$4}NF--' OFS='\t' myFile
chr1    629031  GT:CN   1/1:4
chr1    632301  GT:CN   0/1:3
chr1    6440431 GT:CN   0/1:2
chr1    16691021        GT:CN   1/1:1
chr1    6440431 GT:CN   0/1:0
```

Comment: `NF--` is unpredictable and not portable.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo and using print instead of modifying the field,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$4=(($5~/CN/)?"0":"1")"/1:"$4; $5=""}1' file
```

should do what you're trying to do.

Can be further simplified to

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$4=($5!~/CN/)"/1:"$4; $5=""}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {$4 = ($5 ~ /^CN/ ? "0/1:" : "1/1:") $4; sub(/\t[^\t]+$/, "")} 1' f.txt | column -t

chr1  629031    GT:CN  1/1:4
chr1  632301    GT:CN  0/1:3
chr1  6440431   GT:CN  0/1:2
chr1  16691021  GT:CN  1/1:1
chr1  6440431   GT:CN  0/1:0
```

Expanded `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = "\t"
} {
   $4 = ($5 ~ /^CN/ ? "0/1:" : "1/1:") $4
   sub(/\t[^\t]+$/, "")
} 1' f.txt |
column -t
```